# Checkpoint abort on not executing operator

Tags: apache-flink

We have 2 sources.

1. In memory source from an object
2. Kafka stream subscribing source

They both connect at some point

```
Source(from objects) -> Map1 -> CoMap -> Sink
Source(Kafka) -> Map2 -> Map3 -> CoMap -> ...
```

The `Map1` operator is forced to be non parallel

For some reason sometimes we get this kind of log message:

```
INFO  Checkpoint triggering task Source: Source(from objects) -> Map1 (1/1) is not being executed at the moment. Aborting checkpoint.
```

We don't really care about checkpoints for the `Source(from objects) -> Map1` chain.
Can we disable checkpoints there or disable the restoration of them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to some operators finishing and not running.
When an operator is not running no checkpoints can happen.

The solution was to implement a custom SourceFunction and block the thread forever after all the elements were sent